# How do i toggle a class on and off whenever i click on a list item?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to toggle a class on and off whenever i click on a list item. I have tried several things like using classList.toggle and wrapping the list elements in a anchor tag and then trying to add a class to the list items through that but the more things i try the more confused i get.

Here below is the snippet of my code.

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");

li.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    addDoneClass();//
  });

function addDoneClass() {
  li.className = "done"
}
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
  <ul>
      <li random="23">Notebook</li>
      <li>Jello</li>
      <li>Spinach</li>
      <li>Rice</li>
      <li>Birthday Cake</li>
      <li>Candles</li>
    </ul>
```

You might look at my JavaScript code an wonder why i done it that way that is because i was very confused at this point and that was the last thing that i tried.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns an array. you want to add the listener on every child in that array. checking the console while you code stuff should give you good hints on obvious errors.

Comment: Your code doesn't toggle a class.  It only attempts to adds a class... what event should cause the class to be removed?

Answer (score 3):

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("li");

elements.forEach((element) => {
    // First option
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.classList.toggle('active');
    });
    
    // Second option
    //element.addEventListener('click', function() { customHandle(this); });
    
    // Third option
    //element.addEventListener('click', (e) => customHandle(e.target.closest('li')));
});

// For the second and third options
//function customHandle(element) {
//    element.classList.toggle('active');
//}
```

```css
li.active {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Notebook</li>
    <li>Jello</li>
    <li>Spinach</li>
    <li>Rice</li>
    <li>Birthday Cake</li>
    <li>Candles</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: My only modification to this code would be moving to a regular `for(let element of elements) { ... }` loop

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I have a bad English, I can’t give a detailed description

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's better if you add one event listener to the `ul` element, than have multiple for the `li` elements.

You can use `classList.add("class")` and `classList.remove("class")` functions, [more information](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp). You will also need to check if the current item already has the class, for that use the `classList.contains("class")` function.

Here's an example (updated with [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)):

```js
const ul = document.getElementById("list");

ul.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const li = e.target;
  li.classList.contains('done') ? removeDoneClass(li) : addDoneClass(li)
});

function addDoneClass(li) {
  li.classList.add("done");
}

function removeDoneClass(li) {
  li.classList.remove("done");
}
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li random="23">Notebook</li>
  <li>Jello</li>
  <li>Spinach</li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Birthday Cake</li>
  <li>Candles</li>
</ul>
```

Tip: use the [`classList.toggle("class")`](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp), it does the same thing, but it's the cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

You Have To Use "this" Keyword To Reffer The Currently Clicked Element. You Can Achieve This Using JQuery Like This.

```
li.active {   text-decoration : line-through; }

$("li").click(function () {
   this.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with scope.

```
function addDoneClass() {
  li.className = "done"
}
```

In your context, li is an array of list items. Without running, I would guess that clicking on any list item was striking through all of the list items. Instead you need to pass the specific list item that you want changed.

```
li.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  addDoneClass(this); //this is the list item being clicked.
});

function addDoneClass(obj) {
  // Now you can change to toggle if you want.
  obj.className = "done"
  // ie obj.className.toggle("done");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) returns a [nodelist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and [addEventLister](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) can only be applied to one node at a time. So to fix your code you should loop over each `li` in the list. And since you are using the `event` (evt) with `addEventListener`, you can use `event.currentTarget` to get the element clicked.

```js
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("li");
var listItemCount = listItems.length;
for (var i = 0; i < listItemCount; i++) {
  listItems[i].addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    addDoneClass(evt);//
  });
}

function addDoneClass(evt) {
  evt.currentTarget.className = "done";
}
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li random="23">Notebook</li>
  <li>Jello</li>
  <li>Spinach</li>
  <li>Rice</li>
  <li>Birthday Cake</li>
  <li>Candles</li>
</ul>
```